# All's okay except when you make a little mistake

Tags: phrases, expressions, idiom-requests

What's this situation called when you work at a place where you are never appreciated for what you do until one particular day you forget to do something which attracts all the negative sentiments from people around you who would constantly nag and make sniping remarks. It makes you feel like one negative thing nullifies all the positives in you. How would you describe this situation in phrases/expressions/idioms? Idioms needed for both the family situation as well as professional setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the statement "Once I did bad and that I heard ever.  Twice I did good and that I heard never" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80815/what-does-the-statement-once-i-did-bad-and-that-i-heard-ever-twice-i-did-good) Also [What's the English equivalent of the Japanese saying, “A fart ruins 100 days of sermons by the priest”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101497/whats-the-english-equivalent-of-the-japanese-saying-a-fart-ruins-100-days-of)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is certainly similar but all the answer consist of one liners and not idioms or short phrases. It's like rephrasing the situation in question in a better way. I think I will wait for sometime before closing the question :)

Comment: One_commits a crime_, but _makes a mistake_. _Commit,_ like _accuse_, is used for volitional acts, not inadvertent ones.

Comment: @Jony: Actually, I got my two links the wrong way round - I meant to cite the "one fart" question as the actual duplicate. But I think the "once I did bad" one covers much the same ground - where my own answer there summarises the situation as *people are more likely to remember and talk about **your single past mistake** than your many past successes* (which seems to be *exactly* what you're talking about).)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's alright. I have a little query about "A fart..sermons". In this idiom, we assume that 100 days of sermons before the priest farted was _praised_ and enjoyed by the audience right? What I actually wanted would be something like "the sermons was not that enjoyed by audience for the 100 days, they didn't applaud for the priest but when the priest farted, everybody started to embarass him". I think the first one("Once I did bad...") is actually what I was looking for and that you have posted the right link by mistake

Comment: @FumbleFingers As per my first comment, I was hoping for a shorter expression. If I don't get, then probably I will go for the bigger ones. My question was ambiguous probably.