# Saying to cover a few good deeds but person still corrupt

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

Is there a saying that covers the scenario where a ruler does a few good deeds but by and large is corrupt and deceptive ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. 1) What exactly do you mean by a ruler?  It could be anything from a monarch/dictator with unrestricted power to a head of a democratically elected government.  2) What do you mean by ‘corrupt’?  Normally, one one would think of accepting bribes.  Or do your mean more than this?  3). What do you mean by ‘deceptive’ that could not be said of most political leaders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the statement "Once I did bad and that I heard ever.  Twice I did good and that I heard never" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80815/what-does-the-statement-once-i-did-bad-and-that-i-heard-ever-twice-i-did-good) I knew citing that question as a duplicate wouldn't carry the day against 4 other closevotes for entirely different reasons, but I still think it's highly *relevant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a thief, always a thief (or replace 'thief' with 'cheat')

Answer (score 0):

“Not all that glitters is gold,” maybe?

Comment: I am not quite sure how that adage applies in this case. Perhaps if you put it into context...

Comment: The adage is about how something that looks good on the surface can actually be quite different underneath; looks can be deceptive.